# sendmail error "Relaying denied. Proper authentication required. (state 14)."

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, sendmail

I am an absolute newB on sendmail, now I installed sendmail, configured it (as far as i know) added localhost-names, added access entries added virtuser entry, opened port 25 in iptables.

My DNS is pointing to my server!

Now when I connect from another location on the internet, and use telnet server.com 25 and use manual SMTP commands (HELO, MAIL From etc) the mail goes and arrives and gets put to the right user. but When I use another client and it's relayed by (for example google) I get this error back:

Relaying denied. Proper authentication required. (state 14).

What setting did I forget? Any config files I need to post so you can help me?
I use CentOS 5.5 and the latest sendmail rpm

local-host-names:

```
localhost
localhost.localdomain
footballmatcher.com
```

access:

```
Connect:localhost.localdomain           RELAY
Connect:localhost                       RELAY
Connect:127.0.0.1                       RELAY    
footballmatcher.com     OK
```

domaintable = empty
mailertable = empty
trustedusers = empty
virtusertable = empty

sendmail.mc (extract from webmin, so firt line word is not real)

```
Entry type  Line in configuration file  Move
Other   divert(-1)dnl   
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # This is the sendmail macro config file for m4. If you make changes to 
Other   dnl # /etc/mail/sendmail.mc, you will need to regenerate the    
Other   dnl # /etc/mail/sendmail.cf file by confirming that the sendmail-cf package is  
Other   dnl # installed and then performing a   
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # make -C /etc/mail 
Other   dnl #   
Other   include(`/usr/share/sendmail-cf/m4/cf.m4')dnl   
Other   VERSIONID(`setup for linux')dnl 
OS Type OSTYPE(`linux')dnl  
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # Do not advertize sendmail version.    
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl define(`confSMTP_LOGIN_MSG', `$j Sendmail; $b')dnl  
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # default logging level is 9, you might want to set it higher to    
Other   dnl # debug the configuration   
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl define(`confLOG_LEVEL', `9')dnl 
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # Uncomment and edit the following line if your outgoing mail needs to  
Other   dnl # be sent out through an external mail server:  
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl define(`SMART_HOST', `smtp.your.provider')dnl   
Other   dnl #   
Define  define(`confDEF_USER_ID', ``8:12'')dnl  
Other   dnl define(`confAUTO_REBUILD')dnl   
Define  define(`confTO_CONNECT', `1m')dnl   
Define  define(`confTRY_NULL_MX_LIST', `True')dnl   
Define  define(`confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES', `True')dnl  
Define  define(`PROCMAIL_MAILER_PATH', `/usr/bin/procmail')dnl  
Define  define(`ALIAS_FILE', `/etc/aliases')dnl 
Define  define(`STATUS_FILE', `/var/log/mail/statistics')dnl    
Define  define(`UUCP_MAILER_MAX', `2000000')dnl 
Define  define(`confUSERDB_SPEC', `/etc/mail/userdb.db')dnl 
Define  define(`confPRIVACY_FLAGS', `authwarnings,novrfy,noexpn,restrictqrun')dnl   
Define  define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS',`A')  
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # The following allows relaying if the user authenticates, and disallows    
Other   dnl # plaintext authentication (PLAIN/LOGIN) on non-TLS links   
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # PLAIN is the preferred plaintext authentication method and used by    
Other   dnl # Mozilla Mail and Evolution, though Outlook Express and other MUAs do  
Other   dnl # use LOGIN. Other mechanisms should be used if the connection is not   
Other   dnl # guaranteed secure.    
Other   dnl # Please remember that saslauthd needs to be running for AUTH.  
Other   dnl #   
Other   TRUST_AUTH_MECH(`LOGIN PLAIN')dnl   
Define  define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS',`LOGIN PLAIN') 
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # Rudimentary information on creating certificates for sendmail TLS:    
Other   dnl # cd /etc/pki/tls/certs; make sendmail.pem  
Other   dnl # Complete usage:   
Other   dnl # make -C /etc/pki/tls/certs usage  
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl define(`confCACERT_PATH', `/etc/pki/tls/certs')dnl  
Other   dnl define(`confCACERT', `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt')dnl 
Other   dnl define(`confSERVER_CERT', `/etc/pki/tls/certs/sendmail.pem')dnl 
Other   dnl define(`confSERVER_KEY', `/etc/pki/tls/certs/sendmail.pem')dnl  
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # This allows sendmail to use a keyfile that is shared with OpenLDAP's  
Other   dnl # slapd, which requires the file to be readble by group ldap    
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl define(`confDONT_BLAME_SENDMAIL', `groupreadablekeyfile')dnl    
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl define(`confTO_QUEUEWARN', `4h')dnl 
Other   dnl define(`confTO_QUEUERETURN', `5d')dnl   
Other   dnl define(`confQUEUE_LA', `12')dnl 
Other   dnl define(`confREFUSE_LA', `18')dnl    
Define  define(`confTO_IDENT', `0')dnl  
Other   dnl FEATURE(delay_checks)dnl    
Feature FEATURE(`no_default_msa', `dnl')dnl 
Feature FEATURE(`smrsh', `/usr/sbin/smrsh')dnl  
Feature FEATURE(`mailertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/mailertable.db')dnl   
Feature FEATURE(`virtusertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/virtusertable.db')dnl   
Feature FEATURE(redirect)dnl    
Feature FEATURE(always_add_domain)dnl   
Feature FEATURE(use_cw_file)dnl 
Feature FEATURE(use_ct_file)dnl 
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # The following limits the number of processes sendmail can fork to accept  
Other   dnl # incoming messages or process its message queues to 20.) sendmail refuses  
Other   dnl # to accept connections once it has reached its quota of child processes.   
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl define(`confMAX_DAEMON_CHILDREN', `20')dnl  
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # Limits the number of new connections per second. This caps the overhead   
Other   dnl # incurred due to forking new sendmail processes. May be useful against 
Other   dnl # DoS attacks or barrages of spam. (As mentioned below, a per-IP address    
Other   dnl # limit would be useful but is not available as an option at this writing.) 
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_THROTTLE', `3')dnl  
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # The -t option will retry delivery if e.g. the user runs over his quota.   
Other   dnl #   
Feature FEATURE(local_procmail, `', `procmail -t -Y -a $h -d $u')dnl    
Feature FEATURE(`access_db', `hash -T<TMPF> -o /etc/mail/access.db')dnl 
Feature FEATURE(`blacklist_recipients')dnl  
Other   EXPOSED_USER(`root')dnl 
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # For using Cyrus-IMAPd as POP3/IMAP server through LMTP delivery uncomment 
Other   dnl # the following 2 definitions and activate below in the MAILER section the  
Other   dnl # cyrusv2 mailer.   
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl define(`confLOCAL_MAILER', `cyrusv2')dnl    
Other   dnl define(`CYRUSV2_MAILER_ARGS', `FILE /var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp')dnl  
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # The following causes sendmail to only listen on the IPv4 loopback address 
Other   dnl # 127.0.0.1 and not on any other network devices. Remove the loopback   
Other   dnl # address restriction to accept email from the internet or intranet.    
Other   dnl #   
Other   DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp,Name=MTA')dnl 
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # The following causes sendmail to additionally listen to port 587 for  
Other   dnl # mail from MUAs that authenticate. Roaming users who can't reach their 
Other   dnl # preferred sendmail daemon due to port 25 being blocked or redirected find 
Other   dnl # this useful.  
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=submission, Name=MSA, M=Ea')dnl    
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # The following causes sendmail to additionally listen to port 465, but 
Other   dnl # starting immediately in TLS mode upon connecting. Port 25 or 587 followed 
Other   dnl # by STARTTLS is preferred, but roaming clients using Outlook Express can't 
Other   dnl # do STARTTLS on ports other than 25. Mozilla Mail can ONLY use STARTTLS    
Other   dnl # and doesn't support the deprecated smtps; Evolution <1.1.1 uses smtps 
Other   dnl # when SSL is enabled-- STARTTLS support is available in version 1.1.1. 
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # For this to work your OpenSSL certificates must be configured.    
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtps, Name=TLSMTA, M=s')dnl   
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # The following causes sendmail to additionally listen on the IPv6 loopback 
Other   dnl # device. Remove the loopback address restriction listen to the network.    
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`port=smtp,Addr=::1, Name=MTA-v6, Family=inet6')dnl  
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # enable both ipv6 and ipv4 in sendmail:    
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Name=MTA-v4, Family=inet, Name=MTA-v6, Family=inet6')   
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # We strongly recommend not accepting unresolvable domains if you want to   
Other   dnl # protect yourself from spam. However, the laptop and users on computers    
Other   dnl # that do not have 24x7 DNS do need this.   
Other   dnl #   
Feature FEATURE(`accept_unresolvable_domains')dnl   
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl FEATURE(`relay_based_on_MX')dnl 
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # Also accept email sent to "localhost.localdomain" as local email. 
Other   dnl #   
Other   LOCAL_DOMAIN(`localhost.localdomain')dnl    
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # The following example makes mail from this host and any additional    
Other   dnl # specified domains appear to be sent from mydomain.com 
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl MASQUERADE_AS(`mydomain.com')dnl    
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # masquerade not just the headers, but the envelope as well 
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl 
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl # masquerade not just @mydomainalias.com, but @*.mydomainalias.com as well  
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl    
Other   dnl #   
Other   dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost)dnl 
Other   dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost.localdomain)dnl 
Other   dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(mydomainalias.com)dnl 
Other   dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(mydomain.lan)dnl  
Mailer  MAILER(smtp)dnl 
Mailer  MAILER(procmail)dnl 
Other   dnl MAILER(cyrusv2)dnl
```

Comment: as you can see, my domain name is footballmatcher.com

Answer (score 3):

According to your sendmail.mc your sendmail setup supports SMTP authentication and STARTTLS. When you connect "by hand" (telnet) on port 25 you are not using any of these options. However, it seems that your client is setup to connect to your sendmail server and use either SMTP authentication or STARTTLS (or both) and your server, although it claims to support these options, is not properly configured.

Have your client connect to port 25 at the server and uncheck any options that enable STARTTLS, SSL, TLS or SMTP-AUTH. Your other choice is to configurethem properly after reading the [sendmail documentation](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

Use SMTP authorization(local login and password):

```
AUTH PLAIN base64("\000email\000password")
```

or accept to relay your ip in /etc/mail/access

```
192.168.1.1             RELAY
```

and then create map "makemap hash /etc/mail/access.db < /etc/mail/access"

Comment: nothing... my accesslist contains my domain name and ip address with RELAY. I created DNS records directly to my A record, and A record points to my server. Also Created TXT record with SPF (or something) record, which allows that server to relay. local-hosts... file contains all my domain names as well.

Comment: access don't contains domain. it contains "HOST(IP OR DNS) ACTION". add access file and mail log to question.